# Find the equation of the tangent to the curve with exponential function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The question is as follows: Find the equation of the tangent to the curve $y = xe^{2x}$ at the point $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{e}{2})$.

Now I figured out that  $\frac{dy}{dx} = e^{2x}(2x+1)$, and that when I plug in $x=1/2$ then I get that the slope = $2e$.

So at this point I have the original curve's equation, the equation of its differential, the fact that the slope of the tangent at the given point is $2e$ and that this tangent also passes through the point $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{e}{2})$. But I can't seem to arrive at the equation of this tangent.

The answer is

\begin{equation}
y = 2ex - \frac{e}{2}
\end{equation}

but how they got there, I don't know. I've checked other `find the equation of a tangent line to a curve` questions, but still haven't figured my way to that answer. It seems there's something wrong with my assumption that the equation of the tangent line is of the form $y=mx+c$. But how do I know which form it should take?

### Edit

Sorry - I'd written the target answer above wrong. I edited it to correct it.

Comment: Do you mean $2ex-e/2$?

Comment: I think it should be $2ex-\frac{e}{2}$ so that it passes through $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{e}{2})$.

Comment: That that you say is the answer can't possibly be correct as it is not the equation of a straight line...

Comment: You're right... it was 2ex not e^x, I've edited the question. But even with this I seem to be making some fundamental mistake and can't arrive at it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of a line of slope $m$ passing through a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is

$$y-y_0 = m (x - x_0)$$

Here, $m=2 e$, $x_0 = \frac{1}{2}$, and $y_0 = \frac{e}{2}$.  Plug away.

Answer (score 0):

so 1. F(x) = xe^2x

1. F(x)'= e^2x (2x + 1)
2. slope when you substitute x=1/2 = 2e
3. y - e/2 = 2e (x - 1/2)

y= 2ex - e + e/2

Y= 2ex - e/2